# Why is that some anime never see light of day?

Tags: anime-production

Some anime pilots get made, but not every pilot does. Why is that?

Comment: Possible self-duplicate? [Why is that some anime anthology films are cancelled?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/62405/2516)

Answer (score 3):

The pilot didn't get the reaction they wanted, and they conclude that it won't be a money maker.

It is, after all, a business.