# Why did they never finish the anime adaptation of "School Live?"

Tags: anime-production, gakkou-gurashi

I remember watching the show *School Live* back in 2018 with my sister on a rainy day, and when we got to the end of the 12 episode core, we thought it was done, and it seemed like it from the way they left it. Around the end of my previous school year (May to June) I read all 12 of the volumes. Here's where I get confused. The anime cuts off with them leaving the school because there had been a fire and all the Zombies get inside until Yuki makes them leave. The way the fire starts is different from the manga too. But the manga continues with them moving around until they get to the college and meet with the "para-military" group consisting of former college students. So on and so forth. The anime never continues to this point, and with many announcements that turn out to be false, at this point I don't know if it'll happen. So, I was wondering why this is. Could someone please explain?

Comment: "*with many announcements that turn out to be false*" were the announcements coming from the official sources, or 3rd-party articles with the usual clickbait headline?

Comment: Also related: [Why don't anime shows finish the manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/34468/2516), [Why do anime production studios never seem to announce if they plan to cancel a series, often just leaving it in limbo for years?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/57867/2516)